# how to merge object in class?

Tags: c++

I have a big issue in practice coding.
if I have it code how can I merge them?

```
class Box {
    int a, b;
    public:
        Box() {
            a=1, b=2;
        }
        Box(int a,int b) {
            this -> a = a
            this -> b = b;
        }

        Box operater+ (Box op2);
        void merg(Box c);
};
Box Box::operator+(Box &op2) {
Box tmp;
tmp.a=this->a +op2.a;
tmp.b=this->b +p[2.b;
}
```

I completed coding without merge(box c), but I couldn't code merge(box c)
I want to make this
If I write

```
int main() {
    Box A(1,2), B(3,4);
    A.merg(B);
}
```

then A become (4,6)
how could I code this merg?
I edited this like

```
void Box::merg(Box c) {
    this->a=this ->a +c.a;
this->b=this->b + c.b;
}
```

But it does not use operator.
I want to make merg(Box c) using operator If I write class1 + class2, then a1 become a1+a2  and b1 become b1+b2.

Comment: So you want `a` to be {4, 6}? Then `Box::merge()` needn't return anything. Just do `this->a += box.a`, same for `b` considering the parameter to `merg()` is `box`. Also you can pass the parameter as const reference

Comment: Too many mistakes. Returning a `Box` from a `void` function. Using `operator+` without defining it. `Box(int a, b)` instead of `Box(int a, int b)`. Typo: `operater+`.

Comment: If I use
void Box::merg(Box a) { 
this->a+= box.a;
this->b +=box.b;
}
I do not need to use operator?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Something like this:

```
void Box::merg(Box box2) {
    this->a = this->a + box2.a;
    this->b = this->b + box2.b;
}
```

You could also do something like this, then you use both the operator and the function:

```
      Box operator+(const Box& b) {
         this.merg(b);
         return this;
      }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I edited my post. If I use that method, I don't need to write operator. Then How could I code merg() using operator? I want to make this like 
class1 =class1+ class2 I want this code simple not writing all part, just write class name. 
@Ivan

Comment: There's actually that example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm)